# Promise to execute a function after a parameter of a class was set in Angular 4

Tags: node.js, angular, asynchronous, angular-promise

I have a class, and this class has a parameter "filter".  This class also accepts input filterChange. On change in filterChange, I want to set filter to a new value, and THEN execute a function that will use this.filter. Because Angular 2 is asynchronous, I would like to know how to guarantee that filter will have a new value before sampleFunction runs. What is the right way to do this? I was thinking about writing a promise that would set this.filter to filterChange and then use .then to call sampleFunction, but it seems that I cannot use "this" within Promise scope.

```
export class StackOverFlowExample implements OnChanges{
   filter = 'default';
   constructor(){}
   @Input filterChange;

   ngOnChanges(){
      this.filter = this.filterChange;
      this.sampleFunction(); //how to make sure this gets the updated this.filter value?
   }

   sampleFunction(){
      //uses this.filter;
   }
}
```

Also, I know I can  have sampleFunction accept a filter value, and do something like: sampleFunction(this.filterChange), but this is not the behavior I am looking for.

Or, is Angular not as asynchronous as I imagine and thereby this code is Ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve using set/get ES6 methods.

```
export class StackOverFlowExample implements OnChanges{
   filter = 'default';
   constructor(){}
   @Input filterChange;
   private previousValue;

   ngOnChanges(){}

   set filterChange(value){
     if(this.previousValue != value){
        this.filter = value;
        this.previousValue = this.filter;
      this.sampleFunction(); //how to make sure this gets the updated this.filter value?
     }
   }

   sampleFunction(){
      //uses this.filter;
   }
}
```

Comment: This looks elegant! One question. This.filter and this.sampleFunction() are still being called without any synchronization. is it possible for this.sampleFunction() to use the old value of this.filter because this.filter took longer to update than it took for sampleFunction to call this.filter? Or is that not a concern?

Comment: @RebeccaK375 There is really nothing in your code that is asynchronous. Can you show more code to describe your problem?

Comment: That was my question - whether this is considered to be async code or not (the idea of one variable being set and then that variable being used by another function), but it sounds like that is O.K. Also, thank you for showing the set method!

Answer (score 1):

Simple if condition would work. Compare `previous` and `current` values within `ngOnChanges` method

```
ngOnChanges(changes : SimpleChanges){
     if(changes['filterChange'] != undefined && 
         changes['filterChange'].previousValue != changes['filterChange'].currentValue) {
         this.filter = this.filterChange;
         this.sampleFunction();
     }
}
```